# How to download, modify and serve distant page

Tags: node.js, express, https, http-proxy

I try to create a http server that will download the HTML at `https://google.com`
And serve it (at localhost:3000). Kind of a proxy.

With this code:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')

const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, mainRes) {
    https.get('https://www.google.fr', (res) => {
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            mainRes.send(d)
        })
    })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

The html from google.com seems to be downloaded, but the server crashes with this error :

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I Understand it's related to the 2 wrapped requests but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the argument `res` is a stream (see the docs for [`https.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback)).

Currently you are attempting to send the complete response each time a chunk is received through that stream. Hence you are getting the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`, because the second time `mainRes.send()` is called you are trying to send the whole response again. (See the docs for express' [`res.send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).)

You want to pipe `res` through the express response object, as this is also a stream:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')

const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, mainRes) {
    https.get('https://www.google.fr', (res) => {
        mainRes.pipe(res)
    })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Thanks, no errors anymore, but this snippet doesn't seem to return anything and localhost:3000 keeps spinning, before timing out. Also, what if I want to modify the html of google.com ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure in your case but I would suggest you to add a debugger statement and step through it.

Answer (score 0):

@sdgluck && @kwesi1337 helped me find a solution, I need to concat all chunks from the `data` event :

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')

const app = express()
let data = ''

app.get('/', function (req, mainRes) {
    https.get('https://www.google.fr', (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            mainRes.end(data);
        });
    })
})

app.listen(3000)
```